# Using templates to allow usage of arbitrary LinAlg libraries

Tags: c++

I have a function that performs some linear algebra calculations, for which I currently use [the Eigen library](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/index.php?title=Main_Page).

The function looks like that:

```
void Predict(const MatrixXd& F,
        VectorXd& x,
        VectorXd& u,
        MatrixXd& P,
        MatrixXd& Q)
    {
        x = F*x + u;
        P = F*P*F.transpose() + Q;
    }
```

Now I want to generalize this function using templates, such that a client can use an arbitrary LinAlg library. My first approach looks like this:

```
template<typename Matrix, typename Vector>
    void Predict(const Matrix& F,
        Vector& x,
        Vector& u,
        Matrix& P,
        Matrix& Q)
    {
        x = F*x + u;
        P = F*P*F.transpose() + Q;
    }
```

The obvious problem however is, that the function depends on a `transpose()` method. Although the underlying functionality should be implemented by any LinAlg - implementation, the signatures of the according methods can and very like will vary. One solution would be to pass the transposed Matrix as a parameter, which would work in this case, but not in cases where this can't be calculated beforehand. So whats the best way to abstract away constraints like this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Provide a wrapper template function:

```cpp
template<typename Matrix>
Matrix transpose(const Matrix& m
{
    return m.transpose();
}
```

And use it:

```cpp
template<typename Matrix, typename Vector>
void Predict(const Matrix& F,
    Vector& x,
    Vector& u,
    Matrix& P,
    Matrix& Q)
{
    x = F*x + u;
    P = F*P*transpose(F) + Q;
}
```

If you ever have a library with some different syntax, specialise or overload the template:

```cpp
SpecialMatrixImplementation transpose(SpecialMatrixImplementation const& m)
{
    m.calculateTransposition();
}
```

This is the same idea coming with e. g. [`std::begin()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/begin) and [`std::end()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/end) functions...

Comment: And `std::hash` (in a broader scope of functors)

Comment: @StoryTeller boost::hash does this properly. std::hash is an abomination.